# Token in Shortcuts

Tags: 7, tokens

Does anybody know of a way to use tokens in a shortcut link? Background: I would like to link to a users IMCE Browser at `http://DRUPALSITE/user/[current-user:uid]/imce` from the shortcuts bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem: The [me aliases](http://drupal.org/project/me) plugin replaces a defined placeholder (normally "me") with the uid of the current user:

Example: `user/me/imce` for the admin aliases to `user/0/imce`.

It's not very flexible though, as it can only replace the uid.